# wordpress URL end with a number

Tags: wordpress

I am not sure if this is a known issue or suppose to be like this performance,

any wordpress website, if you put a number at the end of the URL, for example,

```
http://perishablepress.com/wordpress-multisite-mamp/
```

we put 1 or any numbers at the end

```
http://perishablepress.com/wordpress-multisite-mamp/123
```

We will not get the `NOT FOUND` page, we'll still stay at the same page, which is

`http://perishablepress.com/wordpress-multisite-mamp/`

Is this an error or normal ? how do we redirect to NOT FOUND PAGE instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an error, the `123` is interpreted as a pagination parameter:

```
Request: wordpress-multisite-mamp/123
Query String: page=%2F123&name=wordpress-multisite-mamp
Matched Rewrite Rule: ([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$
Matched Rewrite Query: name=wordpress-multisite-mamp&page=%2F123
```

Posts can be paginated with `<!--nextpage-->`. WordPress displays the content of the last page if no further content is found (or the full post if the post is not paginated).

To redirect to the 404 page when the pagination parameter exeeds the number of pages, drop the following in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so16179138_template_redirect', 0 );
function so16179138_template_redirect()
{
    if( is_singular() )
    {
        global $post, $page;
        $num_pages = substr_count( $post->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->' ) + 1;
        if( $page > $num_pages ){
            include( get_template_directory() . '/404.php' );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated for the answer and explanation. Been searching for a solution a while. Thanks