# Set 404 if url ends numeric

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress i've set the permalink settings to "post name". So the custom structure is: `http://example.com/%postname%/`

When I go to my test page (http://example.com/test/) it returns a 200 status code which is fine. But when I go to http://example.com/test/1234 it returns also a 200. How can I display the 404 page (and 404 result code) when the page ends with numbers?

Comment: This may be helpful. Have a look at **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179138/wordpress-url-end-with-a-number**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to get the $_GET value

```
<?php
    if(is_int($_GET['your_var'])){
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }
?>
```