# How can I split a WordPress page into multiple URLs?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, pagination

I'd like to create a checkout page with multiple steps. Ideally, the URLs would follow a scheme like `/checkout/1`, `/checkout/2`, etc.

I'm familiar with the feature of using `<!--nextpage-->` in the post content to produce pagination "clickbait-style", yielding URLs like `website.com/checkout/1`, `website.com/checkout/2`, etc. But the content to be divided up would be entirely in the template file and not within `post_content`.

How can I add `/2`, for example, to a URL, parse it, and return the contents relevant to Step 2?

Answer (score 0):

The number on the end of a pretty WordPress URL is interpreted as a page number by default, as [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16180210/378183).

So, in the template file, you can `get_query_var('page')` and display content based on the (integer) value returned.